# jQuery autocomplete RegExp for highlight words

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, autocomplete

I'm using renderItem to highlight words from search input, but i need on some way to ignore last spaces.

For example

```
var term = '123';
```

result

**123** 456

456 **123**

But if

```
var term = '123 ';
```

Than will highlight only

**123** 456

456 123

And i need to highlight 123 everywhere or in some way to ignore spaces in term

This is function.

```
_renderItem: function (ul, item) {
    var newlabel = String(item.value).replace(
            new RegExp(this.term,"ig"),
            "<strong>$&</strong>");
    return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<div>" + newlabel + "</div>")
        .appendTo(ul);
}
```

Comment: you want 123 to match with '123456' but not with '123 456', right?

Comment: Use whitespace boundaries: `.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\s)(' + this.term.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + ')(?!\\S)', 'ig'), "$1<strong>$2</strong>")`

Comment: @Hamza Arshad no i need match all 123

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew this for some reason does not match any words

Comment: See https://ideone.com/j5n45k, it does what you asked for.

Comment: Yes but what about var term = '123   '; ?

Comment: @Fujicu Just `.trim()` it first. See https://ideone.com/XaEHkM. You are not going to highlight whitespace anyway (it makes no sense).

Comment: Actualy .trim is key in this situation, i forgot about trim :(
.replace(new RegExp(this.term.trim(),"gim"), "<strong>$&</strong>"); working as i want